# xlwings writing to range on specific sheet

Tags: python, excel, range, xlwings

I have been trying to write some lists to a certain sheet on a workbook but am having no luck. My code is:

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings import Range
from xlwings import Book
wkb = xw.Book('Master_v3.xlsm')
sht = wkb.sheets['Control']
sht.Range('A1').value = some_list
```

This gives me the error:

```
*** AttributeError: 'Sheet' object has no attribute 'Range'
```

When I use "0" instead of specifying the sheet name (i.e. "Control") this seems to work. Where am I going wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xw.Range` is a shortcut for the Range on the active sheet of the active book of the active app.

When you fully qualify like you do, then `range` is an attribute of the sheet object, which follows the Python naming conventions of lower case for attributes:

`sht.range('A1').value = some_list`

I.e. mind `xlwings.Range` vs. `mysheet.range`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
import xlwings
wb = xlwings.Book(r"filename")
wb.sheets['Sheet1'].range((5,1),(195,13)).value = ...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format your posts properly.

Comment: I am tyring to write a dataframe without the index, any idea how i can get it working.